# How to display Custom Advertisement Banner Images with Animation in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, banner

I have a set of images say 10 images. I want to display those images at bottom of the screen one after the other with animation.

It looks like iAd or ADBannerView that will show with animation and disappear with animation.

Images are coming from server with URL links. I need to show them like advertisements at bottom of the screen.

I used below code

https://github.com/alobi/ALAlertBanner

But it is not displaying the images in some scenarios..(When using Timers or Navigating to some other screen and coming back to this view)

Below is my code

```
_secondsToShow = 10;
_showAnimationDuration = 5;
_hideAnimationDuration = 5;

self.bannerTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:20.0 target:self                                                  selector:@selector(showAdvertisementsInView) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

[self.bannerTimer fire];

- (void)showAdvertisementsInView {

    appDelegateRef.imageIndex=appDelegateRef.imageIndex+1;

    ALAlertBannerPosition position = ALAlertBannerPositionBottom;
    //ALAlertBannerStyle randomStyle = (ALAlertBannerStyle)(arc4random_uniform(4));
    banner = [ALAlertBanner alertBannerForView:self.view style:ALAlertBannerStyleSuccess position:position title:nil subtitle:nil tappedBlock:^(ALAlertBanner *alertBanner) {
        NSLog(@"tapped!");
        [alertBanner hide];
    }];
    banner.secondsToShow = self.secondsToShow;
    banner.showAnimationDuration = self.showAnimationDuration;
    banner.hideAnimationDuration = self.hideAnimationDuration;
    [banner show];
}
```

So, Is any alternative solution other than using iAd or AdMob or ALAlertBanner for my problem..

Thanks in Advance...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in your viewController and trigger it off a repeating NSTimer.

```
    {
    NSArray *theImageFileNames; //array of image names
    NSUInteger bannerNumber; //where we're up to
    UIImageView *banner; //was setUpInViewDidLoad or nib or whatever..
    }




    -(void ) cycleToNextBanner{

    bannerNumber ++;
    bannerNumber %= [theImageFileNames count];
    UIImageView *newBanner = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame: banner.frame];
    [newBanner setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[theImageFileNames objectAtIndex:bannerNumber]]];
    [UIView transitionFromView:banner toView:newBanner duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp completion:^(BOOL finished){

if (finished) banner = newBanner;`
   }];


    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering..I will check and let u know...!

Comment: Thanks it is useful for me...+1 for it...!

Answer (score 0):

There is a UIImage extension named '[UIImage+Sprite](https://github.com/r3econ/UIImage-Sprite-Additions)'

You need to give just single sprite image with rectangle specified in it like following code:

```
UIImage *spriteSheet = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bird-sprite-sheet-i5"];

NSArray *arrayWithSprites = [spriteSheet spritesWithSpriteSheetImage:spriteSheet
                                                          spriteSize:CGSizeMake(240, 314)];
[self.imageView setAnimationImages:arrayWithSprites];
```

you can assign 'arrayWithSprites' with your own array of images; Now it will repeat.